# Using custom rails admin action to render app view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am trying to create a custom action in rails admin. I have the action setup in the sense that the icon is now present and can click on it but I am trying to figure out how to get the action to do what I want it to. Essentially I need it to render a view that I have setup in app/views/...etc. I can't seem to find any examples on how to do this and if it is even possible.

The view can be accessed outside of the rails_admin portal by going to: `www.myapp.com/clerk/<some_id>`. I need to action in rails_admin to take me to this page.

Most examples i see either call and API on the object or some function on the object... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have a corresponding action in a controller, defined in routes.rb and a view it renders? I'm trying to figure out how much you have in place already and if I actually understand what you're asking.